# android studio 3.1 cannot find device only in the dialog

Tags: android-studio, adb

Today I got a problem .There is neither usb device nor virtual device in the dialog.
But I can find device with commond.
Maybe there is something wrong with Android Studio.
How can I fix the problem?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a day,I found the problem. The error is

```
WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - Unable to open connection to: localhost/30.129.144.64:5037, due to: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
```

So I add localhot 127.0.0.1 to host file，and then restart AS.Everything is OK